# using And in predicate for lambda expression

Tags: c#, .net, lambda

how to use "And" in predicate in lambda expression. I am trying to achieve something like
this
   new Class1("Test",Status => Status == 18 && 19 && 20)

Please reply

Thanks
Sharath

Comment: i am using C#.net, Framework 3.5

Answer (score 10):

You need to break up your conditional statement into 3 different evaluations - you cannot combine them like you have.

```
Status => Status == 18 && Status == 19 && Status == 20
```

Although, I'm guessing you're wanting an or operator here, because Status cannot have a value of 18, 19, AND 20.  If you're trying to do a bitmask, you want the & operator, and even then a bitmask of 18, 19 & 20 doesn't make a lot of sense to me (though who knows your use case).

```
Status => Status == 18 || Status == 19 || Status == 20
```

Comment: @Sharath this is when you click 'Accept' on @Matt's answer

Answer (score 0):

Good answer so far - consider also `.Any`

```
List<int> favNumbers = new List<int>(18, 19, 20);
Func<int, bool> pred =
  Status => favNumbers.Any(f => f == Status) ;
```